# Python: Json.load large json file MemoryError

Tags: python, json

I'm trying to load a large JSON File (300MB) to use to parse to excel. I just started running into a MemoryError when I do a json.load(file). Questions similar to this have been posted but have not been able to answer my specific question. I want to be able to return all the data from the json file in one block like I did in the code. What is the best way to do that? The Code and json structure are below:

The code looks like this.

```
def parse_from_file(filename):
    """ proceed to load the json file that given and verified,
    it and returns the data that was in the json file so it can actually be read
    Args: 
        filename (string): full branch location, used to grab the json file plus '_metrics.json'
    Returns: 
        data: whatever data is being loaded from the json file
    """

    print("STARTING PARSE FROM FILE")
    with open(filename) as json_file:    
        d = json.load(json_file)
        json_file.close()
        return d
```

The structure looks like this.

```
[
    {
        "analysis_type": "test_one",
        "date": 1505900472.25, 
        "_id": "my_id_1.1.1",
        "content": {
            .
            .
            .
        }
    },
    {
        "analysis_type": "test_two",
        "date": 1605939478.91,
        "_id": "my_id_1.1.2",
        "content": {
            .
            .
            .
        }
    },

    .
    .
    .
]
```

Inside "content" the information is not consistent but has 3 distinct but different possible template that can be predicted based of analysis_type.

Comment: try ujson library. UltraJSON is an ultra fast JSON encoder and decoder written in pure C with bindings for Python 2.5+ and 3.

Comment: If you want the entire data structure in memory, I'm not sure you have any options other than increasing memory. If you can process the JSON sequentially a bit at a time, maybe you can use something like [this](http://softwaremaniacs.org/blog/2010/09/18/ijson/en/)?

Comment: As a side note, if you are using a `with` statement why are you closing the file manually? Thats what the `with` statement do for you. Also, I would unindent the `return` statemen to the level of the `print` function and `with` statement, but that may be a personal preferance, as both options do the same, it just would close the file a few instructions earlier.

Comment: @yudongshen why are you offering him a "ultra fast" decoder if his problem is with memory? ujson may be more memory efficient, Im not sure about that, but then thats is what you should say about ujson and not it being ultra fast. Your comment looks like just merchandising of a certain package.

Comment: @Adirio, i just copy from ujson's introduction, i used this lib, just remember that it is very efficient. not sure about a 300 MB size file.

Comment: ujson gives me a " ValueError: Could not reserve memory block " so I do not think that will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i did like this way, hope it will helps you. and maybe you need skip the 1th line "[". and remove "," at a line end if exists "},".

```
with open(file) as f:
    for line in f:
        while True:
            try:
                jfile = ujson.loads(line)
                break
            except ValueError:
                # Not yet a complete JSON value
                line += next(f)
        # do something with jfile
```

Answer (score 0):

If all the tested libraries are giving you memory problems my approach would be splitting the file into one per each object inside the array.

If the file has the newlines and padding as you said in the OP I owuld read by line, discarding if it is `[` or `]` writting the lines to new files every time you find a `},` where you also need to remove the commas. Then try to load everyfile and print a message when you end reading each one to see where it fails, if it does.

If the file has no newlines or is not properly padded you would need to start reading char by char keeping too counters, increasing each of them when you find `[` or `{` and decreasing them when you find `]` or `}` respectively. Also take into account that you may need to discard any curly or square bracket that is inside a string, though that may not be needed.